# How to adjust the position of the element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 elements: well, with some information inside and button which located under the well. How can I partially impose button on top of the well like on the picture?

[image]

Here's the code of the elements:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-offset-2" align="center">
       <div class="well" align="center">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
         <br><b >Here</b></br>u can find simple text
         </p>
       </div><!--EO Well--->
       <div class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Click here</div>
     </div> <!--EO Col--->
     </div><!--EO Row--->
</div><!--EO Container--->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go is setting up the `margin-top` add something like this in the `css`

```
.btn-lg {
margin-top: -50px;
}
```